# File_In_Use Deployment Fail while deploying through continues delivery

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

I have configured continuous delivery in my Azure Web App. Everything works fine. Until 2 days before, it started throwing error stating the file is locked(Error_File_In_Use).

There is a hack mentioned in many stack overflow and GitHub issues. i.e. deleting the WebConfig file and re deploying it.

But I would like to know about a permanent solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could stopping the website before the deployment and starting after the deployment does release the lock. [**stop – deploy – restart**]

Please refer to the solutions in this case: [Azure App Service Deploy file in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41055739/azure-app-service-deploy-file-in-use)

Or you could refer to Frank Boucher's answer in this link: [Visual Studio Team Services: Azure Web App Deployment failure – ERROR_FILE_IN_USE](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuredev/2016/05/22/visual-studio-team-services-azure-web-app-deployment-failure-error_file_in_use/).